# Unable to select spinner item in android

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-studio-4.0

I have added a spinner and loaded the a list into it. Using the `app` I want to select from a list. But I am unable to do it.

```
 subDivisionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            if (isUserAction) {
                if (position != selectedSubDivisionPosition) {
                    resetForm(false, false);
                }
            }
            selectedSubDivision = subDivisionList.get(position);
            selectedSubDivisionPosition = position;
            isUserAction = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

When I click on spinner the list does shows but when I click on an item it goes back to the original state. i.e. the selected item is not shown after taping on it. See below image

[image]

**Update 1**

Below is my `resetForm` method

```
private void resetForm(boolean all, boolean signal) {

    this.refNofield1.setText("");
    this.consumerNameEditText.setText("");
    this.consumerAddressEditText.setText("");
    this.longitudeEditText.setText("");
    this.latitudeEditText.setText("");
    this.placeEditText.setText("");
    this.tarifEditText.setText("");
    this.sLoadEditText.setText("");
    this.cableLengthEditText.setText("");
    this.runningLoadEntryA.setText("");
    this.runningLoadEntryB.setText("");
    this.runningLoadEntryC.setText("");
    this.ctRatio.setText("");
    this.transformerRating.setText("");
    this.newSurveyImagesBitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    this.newSurveyImageSliderAdapter.setSliderImages(this.newSurveyImagesBitmap);
    this.imagesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    latestSelectedImagePath = "";
    refNo = "";
    customerId = "";
    imageCount = 0;
    meterLocationRadioGroup.clearCheck();

    meterTypeSpinner.setSelection(0);
    meterTypeDesiredSpinner.setSelection(0);
    meterTypeFieldSpinner.setSelection(0);
    installTypeSpinner.setSelection(0);
    meterStatusSpinner.setSelection(0);
    CtRatioSpinner.setSelection(0);
    TransfRateSpinner.setSelection(0);
    transformerTypeSpinner.setSelection(0);
    subDivisionSpinner.setSelection(0);
    //meterTypeSpinner.setSelection(0);
    selectedMeterType = "";
    zongDataRateEdittext.setText("");
    mobilinkDataRateEdittext.setText("");
    telenorDataRateEdittext.setText("");
    ufoneDataRateEdittext.setText("");

    enableDisableDataRateEntry(false);
    enableDisableOperators(false,false);

    if (all) {
        setSubDivs();
    }

    isatbSealedChecked = false;
    atbSealedCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
    ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);

    if (signal) {
        zongRadioGroup.clearCheck();
        waridRadioGroup.clearCheck();
        mobilinkRadioGroup.clearCheck();
        telenorRadioGroup.clearCheck();
        if (isMobilinkChecked) {
            mobilinkCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (isWaridChecked) {
            waridCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (isTelenorChecked) {
            telenorCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (isZongChecked) {
            zongCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        zongType = "";
        mobilinkType = "";
        telenorType = "";
        waridType = "";
        zongDataRate = 0;
        waridDataRate = 0;
        telenorDataRate = 0;
        mobilinkDataRate = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tell us what does resetForm() does and it would be better if you give us that function code as well

Comment: seems like the issue is in `resetForm(false, false)` method which is resetting the value so add the complete code.

Comment: `resetForm()` is my method to reset the form fields.

Comment: @AgentP code is added you can check

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Sample code is added please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [@Pavneet_Sing Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636778/6854117). I have done the following and it's working now

```
private void resetForm(boolean all, boolean signal)
{
    if(all || signal)// if both true then reset form otherwise not
    {
        this.refNofield1.setText("");
        this.consumerNameEditText.setText("");
        this.consumerAddressEditText.setText("");
        this.longitudeEditText.setText("");
        this.latitudeEditText.setText("");
        this.placeEditText.setText("");
        //......
    }



}
```

Comment: Glad to see that you have fixed the flow. Though, you could further optimised this with else case and single boolean flag, `if(all){ // reset all }else{// reset single}`. Extract common settings for all and single to a method and call that method from if-else etc. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

As [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574138/unable-to-select-spinner-item-in-android?noredirect=1#comment110767442_62574138), `resetForm` method is resetting the value of spinner with the first item using

```
subDivisionSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

so comment this and spinner should work as expected

```
private void resetForm(boolean all, boolean signal) {
    ...
    //subDivisionSpinner.setSelection(0); comment this
    //meterTypeSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: `resetForm()` is also called after completion of a process so in this case my `subDivisionSpinner` will not set to `0`

Comment: @Moeez I think the problem is with resetForm itself... did you checked commenting it?

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this , add `isUserAction = true;` before your if statement

```
subDivisionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
       {
           isUserAction = true;

           if (isUserAction) {
               if (position != selectedSubDivisionPosition) {
                   resetForm(false, false);
               }
           }
           selectedSubDivision = subDivisionList.get(position);
           selectedSubDivisionPosition = position;
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });
```

Comment: `private Boolean isUserAction = true;` it's already set true

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this
by moving

> selectedSubDivision = subDivisionList.get(position);
> selectedSubDivisionPosition = position;
> isUserAction = true;

inside else statement.

```
  subDivisionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
    
                if (isUserAction)
                    {
                    if (position != selectedSubDivisionPosition)
                         {
                        resetForm(false, false);
                        }
                    }
                     //MOVE YOUR CODE INSIDE THE ELSE STATEMENT
                   else
                     {
                       selectedSubDivision = subDivisionList.get(position);
                       selectedSubDivisionPosition = position;
                       isUserAction = true;
                     }
              //  selectedSubDivision = subDivisionList.get(position);
              //  selectedSubDivisionPosition = position;
              //  isUserAction = true;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    
            }
   

     });
```